# creating a nested unsorted list from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm struggling to figure out how to create a nested unsorted list from a predefined javascript array. The array looks like this

```
var directory = [
  { type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
  },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
  }
];
```

And the output I'm reaching for is

```
<ul>
  <li>file1</li>
  <li>file2</li>
  <li>HTML files:
    <ul>
      <li>file1</li>
      <li>file2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    file3
  </li>
  <li>JavaScript Files:
    <ul>
      <li>file1</li>
      <li>file2</li>
      <li>file3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: In order to answer this question, what user interface libraries are you using (if any) such as jQuery, react, etc.? Second, can you have directories nested more than one level deep? Meaning a directory inside of a directory inside of a directory, etc.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific: what have you tried and where have you failed?

Comment: @JSager no libraries are being used, the goal is posted below the array

Comment: @alfasin i have no idea where to start. This is my first project using html + javascript with dom manipulation with very little information. Anything that would help would be appreicated

Comment: if you want to get some help from the community you should show you've been working on trying to come with a solution... you can't just post your problem and hope us to give you the solution.

Comment: Generally questions on S.O. do need to show some effort to get answered ("what have you tried?" is what we usually ask the questioner), but if you are really truly unable to get started, here's a hint: Start with `<ul>${directory.map(f)}</ul>` where `f` is a function that, if it sees a type of file, writes the name in an `<li>`, and in type is directory, writes another <ul> and so on..... If you are very new to JavaScript there will be a bit to learn here but you can do it.

Comment: @e.john stack overflow is a bit more of a place where you want to say "Here is where I've tried and here is where I'm stuck", but I don't mind giving you some newbie hints. Assuming you know how to create elements, and how to append children, do some research on the topic of recursion.

Comment: Specifically, a function in JavaScript can call itself. With a little logic, dom manipulation, and looping over children, you can get where you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a few `forEach`'s like below:

```js
var list = [];
var listItem;
var directory = [
  { type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
  },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
  }
];

directory.forEach(element => {
  if (element.type == "file") {
    listItem = "<li>" + element.name.match(/[^.]*/) + "</li>";
    list.push(listItem);
  }
  else if (element.type == "directory") {
    listItem = "<li>" + element.name + "<ul>";
    element.files.forEach(e => {
      listItem += "<li>" + e.name.match(/[^.]*/) + "</li>";
    });
    listItem += "</ul></li>"
    list.push(listItem);
  }
});

document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = list.join('');
```

```html
<h2>Expected Result</h2>
<ul style="background: orange;">
  <li>file1</li>
  <li>file2</li>
  <li>HTML files:
    <ul>
      <li>file1</li>
      <li>file2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    file3
  </li>
  <li>JavaScript Files:
    <ul>
      <li>file1</li>
      <li>file2</li>
      <li>file3</li>
    </ul>
</ul>

<h2>Output</h2>
<ul id="list" style="background: yellow"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function to walk through the directory.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>

  </body>
  <script>
var directory = [
  { type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
  },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
  }
];

function generateList(fdList) {
  let mainUl = document.createElement("UL");
  for (let i = 0; i < fdList.length; ++i) {
    let newLi = document.createElement("LI");
    let fd = fdList[i];
    let textNode = null;
    let fdName = null;
    if (fd.type === 'file') {
      fdName = fd.name.split('.').splice(0, 1)[0];
      textNode = document.createTextNode(fdName);
      newLi.appendChild(textNode);
    } else {
      textNode = document.createTextNode(fd.name);
      newLi.appendChild(textNode);
      newLi.appendChild(generateList(fd.files));
    }
    mainUl.appendChild(newLi);
  }
  return mainUl;
}

document.body.appendChild(generateList(directory));
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know there are already answers, but here is a fun solution using Array.map and templating. It is also recursive and can therefore handle `n` depth.

```js
var directory = [
  { type: 'file', name: 'file1.txt' },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file2.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'HTML Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.html' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.html' }
    ]
  },
  { type: 'file', name: 'file3.txt' },
  {
    type: 'directory',
    name: 'JavaScript Files',
    files: [
      { type: 'file', name: 'file1.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file2.js' },
      { type: 'file', name: 'file3.js' }
    ]
  }
];

const getName = (fileName) => fileName.split('.')[0];
const renderFile = (file) => `<li>${getName(file.name)}</li>`;
const renderDirectory = (data) => data.map(item => (item.type === 'file') ? renderFile(item) : `<li>${item.name}:<ul>${renderDirectory(item.files)}</ul></li>`).join('');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let ul = document.createElement('ul');
  ul.innerHTML = renderDirectory(directory);
  document.querySelector('#target').appendChild(ul);
});
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```